# How to update array of structure from another view in SwiftUi?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

In my *IssueListView* I have a structure:

```
struct MyResults: Codable {
var id: Int
var problem: String
var recordDate: String
var isDone: Bool
var finishedDate: String?
var imagePath: String?
```

}

and a State which is array of the above structure:

```
@State private var myresults = [MyResults]()
```

and every thing work fine as  I use this array to receive data from API *onAppear*() and show it as list in the same view.

**The problem start when I decide to make a new view** (*AddTaskView*) **to add tasks.**

the code adding the new task using API successfully, but I have to dismiss the view after that and my list did not updated as the *onApear* start only once and I don't know how to update the list here inside *AddTaskView* or to make *IssueListView* load the data again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Approach 1: State and Binding

If `myresults` is a `@State` wrapped variable, you should have a `@Binding` variable in `AddTaskView`:

```swift
struct IssueListView: View {
  @State private var myresults = [MyResults]()

  var body: some View {
    yourContentHere
      .onAppear {
        // Load the data from API here.
      }
      .sheet {
        AddTaskView(myresults: $myresults)
      }
  }
}

struct AddTaskView: View {
  @Binding var myresults: [MyResults]

  var body: some View {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Any changes written to `myresults` within `AddTaskView` will reflect and update on `IssueListView` so long as it is passed in `AddTaskView`'s initializer.

### Approach 2: ViewModel

Another great solution is to use [MVVM architecture](https://www.vadimbulavin.com/modern-mvvm-ios-app-architecture-with-combine-and-swiftui/) in your app. Create a View Model for your Results list, and have `myresults` as a `@Published` wrapped property:

```swift
class ResultsViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var myresults = [MyResults]()

  // Add API calls here as methods.
}
```

Then, initialize `ResultsViewModel` in `IssueListView` and pass it to `AddTaskView`:

```swift
struct IssueListView: View {
  @StateObject var viewModel = ResultsViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    yourContentHere
      .onAppear {
        viewModel.someAPICall()
      }
      .sheet {
        AddTaskView(viewModel: viewModel)
      }
  }
}

struct AddTaskView: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: ResultsViewModel

  var body: some View {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, In method #1, I get error in AddTasskView:  Missing argument for parameter 'myresults' in call.    Insert ', myresults: <#Binding<[MyResults]>#>'

Comment: I tried many ways to fix it, 1- first by create mock data in another file, 2- by pass constant variable 3- by pass static variable. the 2, 3 remove the error but the list docent updated

Comment: Since `myresults` is a `@Binding` variable in `AddTaskView`, and it doesn't have an initial stored value, Swift will ask for a `Binding<>` value when initializing `AddTaskView`. So, make sure to call `AddTaskView(myresults: $myresults)` in your view. The `$` passes `myresults` as `Binding<[MyResults]>`.

Comment: I removed the AddTaskView preview part so I don't need to initial or pass parameter. and it's work! Thanks